# RESTful URL design - how to query using OR parameters

Tags: rest, url

How would you design a RESTful query to support OR and AND operand between parameters. Let's say my resource has three fields field1 & field2 &field3. How would you design the URL to enable the following query:

```
"Get myresources where field1=x OR field2=y AND field3=z"
```

Comment: Does AND or OR bind stronger?

Comment: Get myresources where (field1=x OR field2=y) AND field3=z

Answer (score 1):

I would probably encode a normal form (eg. CNF) of the relation between the fields somehow. For example:

```
http://myurl.com/get_myresources?field1=x&field2=y&field3=z&relationcnf=1OR2AND3
```